# Error with psql -c "COPY ... " command

Tags: postgresql, copy, psql

I have a big file to insert into a table so I cannot use pgadmin (and have the PC open for hours to wait that it finishes) and for this reason I have to use the command

```
psql -d DBNAME -c "COPY measurement_realtime FROM '/home/path_to_file/data.csv' DELIMITERS ';';"
```

The table name is correct (I copied and pasted it) but I receive the error

> ERROR: relation "measurement_realtime" does not exist

I really don't understand why... how could I solve it?
Any help and suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: try adding `-U your_agadmin_user` to `psql` - you probably have some search_path set for other user

Comment: thanks for editing message I posted it from mobile phone... however nothing changed adding -U option with user

Comment: Do you know which `schema` your table is? If so, add the schema to the `COPY` command: `COPY the_schema.measurement_realtime ...`.

Comment: schemaname is "public" (only one result in the query to find schema names with that table name) I tried as you suggested COPY public.measurement_realtime... but the error is still here (ERROR: relation "public.measurement_realtime" doesn't exist)...

Comment: How does the table look in the output of `SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'r' AND relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe
[image] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/nnckujzf0zxitv9/Screenshot%202017-08-02%2018.42.55.png?dl=0)

Comment: Looks ok visually. Perhaps there is a space or unprintable character? How does it look in the output of `SELECT convert_to(relname, getdatabaseencoding()) FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'r' AND relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe same as the last screenshot...
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/p9ibmqakv59bl1h/Screenshot%202017-08-05%2013.53.30.png?dl=0" >

Comment: pgAdmin is a pain in the rear... well, try this: `SELECT convert_to(relname, getdatabaseencoding())::text FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'r' AND relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe always the same result... :-/

Comment: Well, then try it with `psql`. It is likely that there are spaces or other strange characters in the name.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe 
ERROR:  type "regnamespace" does not exist
LINE 1: ... WHERE relkind = 'r' AND relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespa...

Comment: You didn't say that you are using an ancient version of PostgreSQL. You'll have to join with `pg_namespace` then.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I didn't know it because I didn't set up the server where I work... however I did the query as you suggested: 
"SELECT convert_to(relname, getdatabaseencoding())::text FROM pg_class,pg_namespace WHERE relkind = 'r' AND relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace;" 
but still error: 
ERROR:  type "regnamespace" does not exist
LINE 1: ... WHERE relkind = 'r' AND relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespa...

Comment: You should learn basic SQL and read the documentation. You can also try querying `information_schema.columns`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I know SQL, why are you saying that?!?

Comment: Well, I keep making suggestions, and instead of trying something yourself, you just keep reporting the errors you get. Do you know what a join is? If not, that's basic SQL. If yes, why didn't you try it? What do you get if you try `convert_to(table_name, getdatabaseencoding())` on `information_schema.tables`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe if I'm here it's because I usually don't use Postgres (because I hate it) but I AM FORCED to use it, not a choice for me, so I asked here for some help, and if I ask help here it's because I already tried all the possibles ideas in my mind... so why are you so aggressive with a person that is simply asking some help??? however as I wrote 1 comment ago I tried the join but nothing changed...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe wrt your last suggestion I tried the query and and this is the result: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/flma4k60x84yuni/Screenshot%202017-08-12%2015.15.30.png?dl=0
obviously the list of elements is longer than in the image but the table where I insert is the query's result...

Comment: Oh, now I have a suspicion - your PostgreSQL (you never said which version it is) is old enough that `bytea` is not displayed as hex. Try something like `SELECT '"' || table_name || '"'` to see if there are any leading or trailing blanks.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I also tried another thing, until now I always worked on the server that they give me but when I tried to replicate the same on my computer (building the db with the same dump file) the problem doesn't exist... however on server version is 9.6.3 on my computer is 9.6.2...
however with that query I got an error (on both):
ERROR:  column "measurement_realtime" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT '"' || measurement_realtime || '"';
                      ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "measurement_realtime" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 15

Comment: That's no surprise because there is no such column (you probably forgot the `FROM` clause in your query).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe no I wrote it (maybe I was wrong with which table I used for the query), I used it into "information_schema.tables" perhaps you mean another table?

Comment: in the end I didn't solve the problem and I use my PC where problem was not present...